# If $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x).g(x))$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove the theorem

> If $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$
>   does not exist, then $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x).g(x))$ does not exist.

but I stuck.

First, I said that this statement is equivalent to the statement

> If $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x)g(x))$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$
>   exits or $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ exists.

but after assuming $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x)g(x))$ exists, I could not reach anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: From the answer, I saw that it is a wrong statement, but still without giving a counterexample, how can we prove it that it is wrong ?

Comment: Duplicate: [Can the limit of a product exist if neither of its factors exist?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/513822/201168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This theorem is obviously wrong:

Take

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if }x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
       0  & \mbox{ otherwise}
         \end{cases}$

and

$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{ if }x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
       1  & \mbox{ otherwise}
         \end{cases}$

then

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0 } f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0 } g(x)$ doesn't exist but $$fg \equiv 0$$ so $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0 } f(x)g(x) = 0$$

Answer (score 4):

The theorem is wrong. Choose e.g. $f(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ -1 & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$. Then the limit of $f$ doesn't exist for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, while it does exist for $fg$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Consider $f$ defined by $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq0$; and $g(x):=-f(x)$. What happens in the case $c=0$?