# Show by means of an example that $\lim_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)]$ may exist even though neither $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

This is particularly a hard problem to solve, "a" has to be a defined number. We can't really pick any two functions simply like $\frac{1}{x}$ and any other to exemplify. Please help me with it

Comment: What do the brackets in $\lim_{x \to a} [f(x)g(x)]$ mean?

Comment: "We can't really pick any two functions simply like $\frac{1}{x}$ and any other to exemplify." -- Is this a limitation by the problem/instructor, or do you just feel it's not possible with $1/x$?

Comment: In any event, probably a pertinent past post -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513822/can-the-limit-of-a-product-exist-if-neither-of-its-factors-exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be equal to $1$ at rational numbers, $0$ at irrational numbers, and let $g(x)$ be equal to $0$ at rational numbers, $1$ at irrational numbers. These two functions have no limits at any point, but the product is simply the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

Take a function $h$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$ does not exist. Define
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}h(x)&\text{ if }x<a\\0&\text{ if }x>a\end{array}\right.,$$
$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0&\text{ if }x<a\\h(x)&\text{ if }x>a\end{array}\right..$$