# Limits of decomposing limits

Tags: limits

**Question:**

Do there exist functions $f$ and $g$ such that 
$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 1 \text{ and } \lim_{x \to c} f(x) g(x) - g(x) \neq 0 \, ?$$
(Allowing, of course, for $\lim_{x \to c}$ g(x) to not exist.)

**Context:**

I am thinking about the limit property that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \cdot g(x) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$.

My understanding is that for this to be guaranteed to hold, we need both limits on the RHS to exist. Indeed, I am familiar with examples for which the two limits on the RHS diverge while the limit on the LHS exists (like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513822/can-the-limit-of-a-product-exist-if-neither-of-its-factors-exist)), as well as examples like $f(x) = 1/x, g(x) = x$ for which the LHS exists but one of the limits on the RHS is zero and the other diverges.

If, however, only one of the limits on the RHS diverges but the other exists *and is nonzero*, will we ever run into trouble by applying this limit property? In some sense, can we modify the requirement that BOTH limits on the RHS exist to the requirement that AT LEAST ONE of the limits on the RHS exists and is nonzero?

Comment: If $g(x)$ is bounded on some neighbourhood of $c$, then no; it is always true that if $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to c$ and $g(x)$ is bounded on some neighbourhood of $c$, then $f(x)g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Counter-example*:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x=1$, and 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos x\,\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=-\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2):

$c=0$, $f(x)=1+x$, $g(x)=1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)g(x)-g(x) = (f(x)-1)g(x)$. By the property you cited (limit of product equals product of limits, if they exist), that means, if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ exists and equals $L$, then by necessecity

$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)g(x)-g(x) = \lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-1)g(x)= \lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-1)\lim_{x\to c}g(x) = (1-1)L = 0.$$

In other words, your remark

> Allowing, of course, for $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ to not exist.

lists in fact the **only case** where your limit can be $\neq 0$. The other answers show that you this your conditiob can actually be fulfilled.